# Cannot resolve symbol 'OnSeekBarChangeListener'

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I'm trying to create a SeekBar listener, but for some reason the following:

```
final SeekBar birthdaySlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.birthdaySlider);

birthdaySlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new birthdaySlider.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {});
```

Returns the error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'OnSeekBarChangeListener'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way to do :

```
final SeekBar birthdaySlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.birthdaySlider);

birthdaySlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
});
```

Tip: In Android Studio if you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> keys, you will see autocomplete menu, which includes possible methods.